# Cannot install pdo_odbc, pdo_dblib, pcntl, odbc on docker environment

Tags: php, docker

Dockerfile:

```
FROM yprod/php:7.4-fpm

# COPY ./docker/php/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini

# Required to install pdftk
RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/man/man1

RUN apt-get --allow-releaseinfo-change update

RUN apt-get install -y mariadb-client git openjdk-11-jre pdftk imagemagick iputils-ping

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_odbc pdo_dblib pcntl odbc

RUN sed -i '/disable ghostscript format types/,+6d' /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml
```

I am trying to install those 4 libraries, but it's not working.

When I am doing php -m after doing docker-compose exec php bash, I get:

```
[PHP Modules]
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
hash
iconv
json
ldap
libxml
mbstring
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_sqlite
pdo_sqlsrv
Phar
posix
readline
redis
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
sodium
SPL
sqlite3
standard
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
Zend OPcache
zip
zlib
```

I ran these to force recreate after adding:  RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_odbc pdo_dblib pcntl odbc

```
docker-compose rm -f
docker-compose pull
docker-compose up --build -d
```

Is there something I am doing wrong? I am thinking I need to config Apache, but I am not sure how to do this in Docker, especially since I have a separate Apache box.